# Is there a mark down to make one or more slanted characters of a word?

Tags: support, markdown

I want to write TikZ but with a slanted *k*. Is there a mark down to do so?

You might have known that typing `Ti*k*Z` does NOT produce the expected result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Q and A posts you can use HTML for this: `Ti<i>k</i>Z`: Ti*k*Z.
But it's not really worth the effort IMHO and will not work for comment and chat messages.